# Realm can't execute executeTransaction inside new Thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, realm, retrofit2

In the above code, realm can't execute its transaction inside the new Thread, no errors are displayed, but its not executed either.

I have already tried to put the transaction outside of the thread, the problem is that it consumes the UI thread, but it works perfectly, and i want to display a smooth loading to the user while Retrofit and Realm do their work

```
threadNova = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();

        try {
            Response<Retorno> response = getCall.execute();
            final Retorno responsebody = response.body();
            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

            realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> {
               //Save things on bank
              // No errors but don't enter here either
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I think this might help ,https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3788

Comment: Can you add the code saving things ?
I guess your are creating a non managed object and forget to save it, so you can do everything you want in your transaction, nothing will be saved ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to call `Realm.close()`.

You using Java Thread without looper it means that your Realm not refreshed until you call `Realm.close()`, so close your Realm inside finally block.

```
    try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
            Response<Retorno> response = getCall.execute();
            final Retorno responsebody = response.body();

            realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> {
               //Save
            });

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

From docs:

> If you obtain a Realm instance from a thread associated with a Looper,
>   the Realm instance comes with an auto-refresh feature. (Android’s UI
>   thread is a Looper.) This means the Realm instance will be
>   periodically updated to the latest version. This lets you keep your UI
>   constantly updated with the latest content with almost no effort!
>
> If you get a Realm instance from a thread that does not have a Looper
>   attached, objects from that instance won’t be updated until you call
>   the waitForChange method. Holding on to an old version of your data is
>   expensive in terms of memory and disk space, and the cost increases
>   with the number of versions between the one being retained and the
>   latest. This is why it is important to close the Realm instance as
>   soon as you are done with it in the thread.
>
> If you want to check whether your Realm instance has auto-refresh
>   activated or not, use the isAutoRefresh method.
>   soon as you are done with it in the thread.

Comment: you dont seem to show how to do that though.